# Using Python in Godot

Tags: python, godot

I understand that this may be a niche question but I'm trying to understand how to work in Godot with Python. I'm using the PythonScript Library Version 0.5 and I have the following code:

```
from godot import exposed, export
from godot import *


@exposed
class Node2D(KinematicBody2D):

    speed = 50
    
    def _physics_process(self,delta):
        velocity = Vector2.ZERO
        if Input.is_action_pressed('ui_up') == True:
            velocity.y -= 1*speed
            
        if Input.is_action_pressed('ui_down') == True:
            velocity.y += 1*speed
            
        move_and_slide(velocity)
```

In it's current state, when I run this, it throws "NameError: name 'move_and_slide' is not defined" although move_and_slide is clearly listed in the KinematicBody2D Methods.

Thanks a lot in advance for your feedback and please let me know if I can clarify this question further.

Answer (score 5):

I actuall found the issue! I needed to add a self. in front of the self.move_and_slide().
Correct code below:

```
from godot import exposed, export
from godot import *


@exposed
class Node2D(KinematicBody2D):

    
    
    def _physics_process(self,delta):
        speed = 50
        velocity = Vector2.ZERO
        if Input.is_action_pressed('ui_up') == True:
            velocity.y -= 1*speed
        
        if Input.is_action_pressed('ui_down') == True:
            velocity.y += 1*speed
            
        self.move_and_slide(velocity)
```

I also needed to move speed in the physics_process function, of which I'm currently not 100% sure why it wasn't noticed outside.

Comment: you could leave speed outside, but then you would have to refer it in the function with self.speed

Comment: Interesting thanks a lot Karol! Can you explain to me why I don't have to define it as self.speed outside the function?

Comment: because python will search for speed in the function's namespace then. If you keep speed variable inside of the function _physics_process this variable will be available only from the code that is inside the function, you won't be able to access it with self.speed anymore.

Comment: here is an article about scopes in Python: https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/

Comment: As a side note I'd recommend avoiding 'from something import *' and instead import specific components.